# When does a matrix fail to be positive definite?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces

I am wondering how to think about a matrix being "bigger" than another.

If I have the inequality X - Omega Sigma^-1 > 0 where all matrices are quadratic and X = Z'Z with Z positive definite and Omega and Sigma^-1 are symmetric and positive definite, will then that inequality imply that X has to be positive definite as well?

I am arriving at this from a change of variable equation and need to make sure that my resulting X is positive definite because I will be integrating over the space of positive definite matrices.

I fear however (somewhat naively) that X > 0 is not the same as the above inequality. If this were a scalar relationship, for example, then the above inequality would exclude certain X that are too small. So, am I missing some 'small' positive definite matrices?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

$Z' Z$ is always positive semidefinite since $x' Z' Z x = (Zx) ' Zx = ||Zx||_2^2 \geq 0$ (when restricted to $||x||=1$, this is the rayleigh quotient).

If $Z$ is positive definite, then the eigenvalues of $Z'Z$ are simply the squares of the eigenvalues of $Z$ which are still positive (use the spectral theorem to write $Z= U D U'$ where $U$ is unitary and $D$ is diagonal with positive diagonal by positive definite-ness). Thus, in this case, $Z'Z$ is positive definite.

Alternatively, note that since $Z$ is p.d., $Z$ has no zero eigenvalues, so $Z$ is full rank and thus $Zx=0$ iff $x=0$. Thus, the inequality for the rayleigh quotient is strict for $x \neq 0$ and thus $Z'Z$ is p.d.

This is independent of the inequality you stated.

Comment: Thank you so much, your explanation really helps me understand all this better! Sadly, I made a mistake in the formulation of my question. What I really meant to ask is does A - B > 0 imply A > 0? The reason is that I have an integral over the space of A - B > 0 and am making a change of variables because I have a nice analytical result derived for integrals over A > 0. My worry however is that the requirement A - B > 0 excludes matrices that are 'close' to failing being pos. def. Is that correct?